# CQWP - using custom column as LinkUrl not working

Tags: content-query-web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom list with custom column - DetailsLink. I would like to render this link in the result of CQWP.

So, my understanding I have to modify ItemStyle.xsl

By default - it generates link to item properties.

So, I went to CQWP properties and changed the value of Presentation/Link field to

DetailsLink [Custom Column]

in a weird way - it accepted the value but when I come back to the properties it's not displaying it.

I modified ItemStyle.xsl to read the value of @LinkUrl and it's still showing default way - link to item's properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your custom column in the webpart properties in the box named Link.
[image: fields to display]

This way the field set in the title box has the link to the field in Link box and not to the item properties.

Comment: yes, the trick was that you must use URL type column - can't use text column